# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not works with tableview

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview, ios5

I had added a UILongPressGestureRecognizer to a tableview in my ViewDidLoad method. I added this to detect long press on table view in my code. But it never works. In ViewDidLoad I added this code :

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                      initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
lpgr.delegate = self;
[self.resultTableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release];
```

I also added this method :

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    CGPoint p = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:self.resultTableView];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.resultTableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:p];
    if (indexPath == nil) {

        NSLog(@"long press on table view but not on a row");
    }
    else {


        NSLog(@"long press on table view at row %d", indexPath.row);
    }


}
```

Please help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code is working. I think you have to add `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` delegate in .h file or how to declare resultTableView i mean you define programmatically or using .xib file.Check it once.

I have tried like this.

```
     resultTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];
     resultTableView =[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 420) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    resultTableView.rowHeight = 100.0;
    resultTableView.delegate=self;
     resultTableView.dataSource=self;
    [self.view addSubview:resultTableView];

    UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                          initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0; //seconds
    lpgr.delegate = self;
    [resultTableView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
    [lpgr release];
```

Comment: resultTableView is in the xib file and Connected using an IBoutlet variable

Comment: @PrasadG when i try to add on tableviewCell . not working.

Comment: [cell.LongGestureVw addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to add the gesture to the individual cells, but you are adding the gesture to the table. Try adding the gesture to your `UITableViewCell` instead.

Comment: adding the gesture recognizer on the tableview is the best way to do this, maybe its something to do with the pan gesture recognizer on the tableview firing before the long press is recognized

Comment: @wattson12: That can be mitigated by `[yourGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tableView.panGestureRecognizer]`.

Answer (score 0):

If the gesture recognizer is being blocked by the `UITableView` panGestureRecognizer, implement the delegate to ensure both can work

```
 -(BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```